# How to count the frequency of integers in a set of querystrings in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in a postgres database which logs search querystrings for a page on our website.

The column contains data like

```
"a=2&b=4"
"a=2,3"
"b=4&a=3"
"a=4&a=3"
```

I'd like to work out the frequency of each value for a certain parameter (a).

```
value | freq
------|------
3     | 3
2     | 2
4     | 1
```

Anyway to do this in a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with all_values as (
  select string_to_array(split_part(parameter, '=', 2), ',') as query_params
  from the_table d, 
       unnest(string_to_array(d.querystring, '&')) as x(parameter)
  where x.parameter like 'a%'
)
select t.value, count(*)
from all_values av, unnest(av.query_params) as t(value)
group by t.value
order by t.value;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/OXM67442

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
select data_value,count(*) from (
  select data_name,unnest(string_to_array(data_values,',')) data_value from (
    select split_part(data_array,'=',1) data_name ,split_part(data_array,'=',2) data_values from (
          select unnest(string_to_array(mydata,'&')) data_array from mytable
         ) a
       ) b
    ) c where data_name='a' group by 1 order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tha table that keeps the counts is called `paramcount`:

```
WITH vals(v) AS
   (SELECT regexp_replace(p, '^.*=', '')
    FROM regexp_split_to_table(
            'b=4&a=3,2',
            '&|,'
         ) p(p)
   )
INSERT INTO paramcount (value, freq)
   SELECT v, 1 FROM vals
ON CONFLICT (value)
   DO UPDATE SET freq = paramcount.freq + 1
      WHERE paramcount.value = EXCLUDED.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get csv integer after 'a='
2. split that to numbers
3. stat values

   ```
   select v, count(*) from (
      SELECT c,unnest(string_to_array(unnest(regexp_matches(c,'a=([0-9,]+)','g')),',')) as v FROM qrs
   ) x group by v;
   ```

Parametrize:

```
WITH argname(aname) as (values ('a'::TEXT))
select v, count(*) from (SELECT c,unnest(string_to_array(unnest(regexp_matches(c,aname||'=([0-9,]+)','g')),',')) as v FROM qrs,argname) x group by v;
```